# Selectize - How to do multiple-select search in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, select, selectize.js, laravel-4.2

I am trying to select multiple values from my selectize and search in my filter. I couldn't achieve it. I am getting error in tec_id in wherein below code.

Blade.php

```
{{ Form::select('tech_filter[]', array(''=> 'Loading...'), null, array('multiple' => 'multiple','id' => 'tech_filter', 'onchange' => 'getAjaxTechList(1)')) }}
```

Script

```
function getAjaxTechList(page) {
            var tech_filter = $('#tech_filter').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/tech/ajax/get/tech?page=' + page + '&search_query=' + search_query               
                + '&tech_filter=' + tech_filter
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#tech_list').html(data);
                $('#loader_tech_list').hide();
                $('#tech_list').show();
                $("#tech_list_table").tablesorter();
                $('.datepicker-webtics').datetimepicker({
                    timepicker: false,
                    format: 'Y-m-d',
                    lang: 'en'
                });
                $('#tech_list_list').foundation();
            });
        }
```

controller

```
public function getAjaxTechList()
    {
        $tech_filter = array();      
        $tech_filter['tech_filter'] = Input::get('tech_filter');
        if($tech_filter != '') {
            $build_query->wherein('tec_id', $tech_filter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you passing in $tech_filter?

Comment: You need to send `tech_filter` as an array.